# Ошибка исполнения после конпиляции pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, pytrovich

После сборки программы видимо из-за модуля pytrovich возникает ошибка, а в пайчарм работает ок.

Error occurred: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\Users\WIN7PRO\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI62002\pytrovich\petrovich-rules\rules.json"
Using possibly outdated rules

Comment: Надо добавить файл pytrovich\petrovich-rules\rules.json в сборку и всё. pyinstaller  --add-data " pytrovich/petrovich-rules; pytrovich/petrovich-rules" ....

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас программа работает, хотя сообщения об ошибках такие же выдает.                 Error occurred: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\Users\WIN7PRO\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI62002\pytrovich\petrovich-rules\rules.json" Using possibly outdated rules                Error occurred: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\Users\WIN7PRO\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI62002\pytrovich\petrovich-rules\gender.json" Using possibly outdated rules

Comment: Добавьте в начале программы input(). Запустите Ваш EXE файл и посмотрите в каталоге C:\Users\WIN7PRO\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI62002\pytrovich\petrovich-rules\ что там реально лежит

Comment: Да, файлы соответствующие там есть, тогда откуда данная ошибка неясно.

Comment: Посмотрите, кто читает эти файлы, вероятно pytrovich и ловите там ошибки. Проверить, что запущены под pyinstaller можно так getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)

Comment: Скриншот ошибки - https://prnt.sc/NGLSPPqayTbP и добавленный код https://prnt.sc/PbPqSkR9EYOr

Comment: Не открываются картинки

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/besU2UjIykGMUw

Comment: Я не вижу, где обращение к JSON файлам

Comment: Оберните кусок с maker=Petrovich.... до director_r в try ... except блок

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/besU2UjIykGMUw Ошибка та же

Comment: Ну значит не тут ошибка - ищи дальше так же с exception, но, я бы в exception после print добавил input(), чтобы найти где этот exception возникает

Comment: Дальше код закомментирован, ошибка все равно есть. Если эти строчки убрать, то ошибки не будет но и код не будет работать.         detector = PetrovichGenderDetector()
        Gender = detector.detect(firstname=director_r[1])
        maker = PetrovichDeclinationMaker() Так код работает, но откуда ошибка не понятно.